# Increment variable based on a cell

Tags: excel, vba

I have this Excel array:

[image]

For each label I have a corresponding variable in memory.
I would like for each line to add the complexity points in the respective variable.

I calculate the sum of all the complexity point with this code:

```
Sub Macro1()

    Dim cellule As Range: Dim memoire As String: Dim sum As Integer
    
    sum = 0
    
    For Each cellule In Selection
        memoire = memoire & cellule.Value & "-"
        sum = sum + cellule.Value    
    Next cellule
    
    MsgBox memoire
    MsgBox sum
    
End Sub
```

I tried to implement the solution for the label "Fonctionnel".

This is my code:

```
Sub Macro2()

    Dim DerniereLigne As Long
    Dim ligne As Long
    Dim memoire As String
    Dim sumFonctionnel As Integer
   
    sumFonctionnel = 0
 
    Dim le_chiffre As Long
    DerniereLigne = Range("A1").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).Row
    For ligne = 1 To DerniereLigne
        If Cells(ligne, 2) = "Fonctionnel" Then
            sumFonctionnel = sumFonctionnel + Cells(ligne, 1).Value
        End If
    Next ligne
    
End Sub
```

But it doesn't work.

Comment: Would help if you [edit] your question and post your current code

Comment: I edited and added my current code

Comment: You have not stated a actual problem. What does not work? Does your code error out? Does nothing happen? Does the wrong thing happen? We need a specific issue to look for in order to debug

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a `Dictionary` object for this: it can keep track of the unique labels and their corresponding sums.

```
Sub SumVals()

    Dim rng As Range, c As Range, dict, v, k

    Set dict = CreateObject("scripting.dictionary")

    'get the input range for the labels
    With ActiveSheet
        Set rng = .Range(.Range("B1"), .Cells(.Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp))
    End With

    For Each c In rng.Cells
        v = Trim(c.Value)
        'if there's a label, add to the count
        If Len(v) > 0 Then dict(v) = dict(v) + c.Offset(0, -1).Value
    Next c

    'output the counts
    For Each k In dict
        Debug.Print "Sum for '" & k & "' is " & dict(k)
    Next k

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Can you explain me what do this line : .Range(.Range("B1"), .Cells(.Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp))

And why we put "." before "Range"

Comment: The `.` is to tie `Range` to the object (ActiveSheet) used in the `With` block.  That line get the range between B2 and the last cell with data in ColB

Answer (score 0):

I see two possible problems, can you post an example of your data? This could be an issue: `Dim sumFonctionnel As Integer` if you have more than 32,767 in the sum it will blow the buffer as that is the limit for integers.

Change it to Long to increase it's limit however if you have decimal points on any numbers both long and int will chop them off so use something like double.

Also don't do this:

```
DerniereLigne = Range("A1").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).Row
```

Do this instead:

```
DerniereLigne = Range("A" & rows.count).end(xlup).Row
```

Last Cell tends to grab white space also, this will grab the last row of actual data in column A.

Can't do much more for you without sample data